# Why $_SERVER is not showing SSL is enabled, when I access the site via https?

Tags: php, https

```
print_r($_SERVER);
```

this is what it shows

```
[SERVER_PORT] => 80
```

why may the `SERVER_PORT` be equal to 80, when I'am accesing the site url via HTTPS protocol?

Comment: Maybe there's a redirect on your server? Are you using a load balancer? Maybe the SSL connection goes to the LB, then it makes an ordinary connection to the real server.

Comment: What webserver are you using? Is the a proxy or load balancer involved?

Comment: @Barmar its a simple apache web server, the $_SERVER variable doesn't show any signs of HTTPS at all, why this happens? the browser url is starting with https tough

Comment: Check your rewrite rules.

Comment: HTTPS can run on 80 and HTTP can run on 443. Probably not here, but port number does not make it SSL.

Answer (score 0):

You need to fully configure your Apache server to get the port to reflect the port in a more consistent manner. According to the PHP documentation:

> Note: Under the Apache 2, you must set UseCanonicalName = On, as well as UseCanonicalPhysicalPort = On in order to get the physical (real) port, otherwise, this value can be spoofed and it may or may not return the physical port value. It is not safe to rely on this value in security-dependent contexts.

http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php